# Formatting a string to include tab characters in Infragistics Ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've been working with an Infragistics Ultragrid and I'm looking for a helpful hint. I'm using a table from SQL Server 2008 to populate my grid. The table that I'm calling has a column that has been updated to be something like this. "Items" + char(9) + char(9) + "Cost" + char(13) + char(10). 
The "Items" section of the column is padded to be 50 charcters in length followed with the two tab characters, the cost then the new line characters. Ultimately this is what the results of a single row would look like. Notice how the items and the cost are lumped into a single cell.

```
Customer A             Chips and Soda           $5.00
                       Chips                    $2.50
                       Burger and Fries         $8.00
                       Fish and Chips           $7.50
                       Hot Dogs                 $4.50
```

When I print my sql server results in Management studio it works as intended. The problems is that when I print the results in the Ultragrid Cell it looks more like this:

```
Customer A              Chips and Soda           $5.00
                        Chips          $2.50
                        Burger and Fries         $8.00
                        Fish and Chips           $7.50
                        Hot Dogs       $4.50
```

One thing to note is that when I copy the contents in the cell and paste them to notepad it looks like the top table. I'm wondering if the width of the empty spaces is shorter than an actual character. If that makes sense? In any case how can I handle the output to be like the top table? Thanks - P Dog

Comment: just for testing, try to change the font of the UltraGrid to Courier New. How does it look now?

Comment: Davide I'm sorry but I will have to try that tomorrow when I go back into work. I left my workstation totally stumped today. But I will definitely try it. Do you think it is the font that makes it appear like table 2?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Davide, my solution was to have the font in the cell be displayed as "Lucinda Sans Typewriter." Now I understand the difference between fixed width fonts (monotype) and variable width fonts like Microsoft Sans Serif.